# The vector quadruple product - Index notation

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I am looking to prove the following using index notation, but I am getting stuck on obtaining the RHS of the statement.

Thus, I wanted to be 100% sure (by asking you guys) that the RHS of the statement below is correct.

That is:

$(\overrightarrow{a}$
$\times$$\overrightarrow{b})$$\times(\overrightarrow{a}$$\times$$\overrightarrow{c})$ $=$ $\overrightarrow{a}$$(\overrightarrow{a}$$\cdot$$\overrightarrow{b}$$\times$$\overrightarrow{c})$.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Better put a ( between the scalar product of $a$ and $ b \times c $. Would help you a lot to know how to use the Kronecker delta and the Levi-Civita tensor and its identities in order to prove it with indexes.

Comment: It is correct.  If all you're looking for is confirmation, next time you can just check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Addition_and_multiplication).  To see that your identity follows from their more general one, just note that $a \cdot (b\times a)=\det(a,b,a)=0$.  Or are you looking for someone to write down the proof in index notation?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bye_World and Bruno. I got to the point where I had three Levi-Civita tensors (on LHS) which simplified to just one and some Kronecker deltas. which is where I am stuck. The RHS has only one Levi-Civita, and I cant see how how to get to the next step. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Next time add the place you are stuck into the question.  I went ahead and just worked the whole problem out because if I just started at the point where I had one Levi-Civita epsilon and some Kronecker deltas you might not know how I got there (if our work up to that point isn't exactly the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem:
$$(a\times b) \times (a\times c) = a(a\cdot (b\times c))$$

Proof:

$$\begin{align}[(a\times b) \times (a\times c)]_d &= \varepsilon_{def}(a\times b)_e(a\times c)_f \\ &= \varepsilon_{def}(\varepsilon_{egh}a_gb_h)(\varepsilon_{fij}a_ic_j) \\ &= \varepsilon_{efd}\varepsilon_{egh}\varepsilon_{fij}a_gb_ha_ic_j \\ &= (\delta_{fg}\delta_{dh} - \delta_{fh}\delta_{gd})\varepsilon_{fij}a_gb_ha_ic_j \\ &= \delta_{fg}\delta_{dh}\varepsilon_{fij}a_gb_ha_ic_j - \delta_{fh}\delta_{gd}\varepsilon_{fij}a_gb_ha_ic_j \\ &= \varepsilon_{gij}a_gb_da_ic_j - \varepsilon_{hij}a_db_ha_ic_j \\ &= \varepsilon_{gij}a_gb_da_ic_j + \varepsilon_{ihj}a_db_ha_ic_j \\ &= a_g(\varepsilon_{gij}a_ic_j)b_d + a_i(\varepsilon_{ihj}b_hc_j)a_d \\ &= a_g(a\times c)_gb_d + a_i(b\times c)_ia_d \\ &= [a\cdot (a\times c)]b_d + [a\cdot (b\times c)]a_d\end{align}$$

---

Lemma:

$$a\cdot (a\times c) = 0$$

Proof:

$$\begin{align} a\cdot (a\times c) &= a_i(\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jc_k) \\ &= -a_i\varepsilon_{jik}a_jc_k \\ &= -a_j\varepsilon_{jik}a_ic_k \tag{commuting terms} \\ &= -a_i\varepsilon_{ijk}a_jc_k \tag{renaming my dummy indices: $i \leftrightarrow j$} \\ &= -a_i(a\times c)_i \\ &= -a\cdot (a\times c) \end{align}$$

The only scalar equal to its negative is zero.  Thus $a\cdot (a\times c) = 0$.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$

---

Using this lemma we see that the first term in our theorem is zero.

Thus $$\begin{align}[(a\times b) \times (a\times c)]_d &= [a\cdot (b\times c)]a_d \\ &= a_d[a\cdot (b\times c)] \\ &= \left[a\left(a\cdot [b\times c]\right)\right]_d\end{align}$$

Because this equality holds for an arbitrary $d$th coordinate of each vector, it holds for the vectors.$\ \ \ \ \square$

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the part proving that a⋅(a×c)=0 that tripped me up. One question, how do you get from saying "The only scalar equal to its negative is zero. Thus a⋅(a×c)=0". Since a.(axc)=-a⋅(a×c), then how can we say it must be equal to zero? Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: $a\cdot (a\times c)$ is a scalar quantity (meaning a real number).  We know (from like 6th grade) that the only real number $k$ such that $k=-k$ is zero (thus $k=0$).  If you don't trust the middle school teacher that told you that the first time and would like to *prove* it, you can do so easily: $$k = -k \\ \implies k+k = 0 \\ \implies 2k = 0 \\ \implies k=0$$  Just substitute $a\cdot (a\times c)$ for $k$ and you get your result.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! Just the vectors made it look like something else was going on. Thanks for all your help.